# if statement inside JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, syntax, jsx

```
class App extends React.Component {

  render() {

    return (

      <div className="bg">
        {productList.map((product) => {
          return (
            <div className="mainContainer">
              <div className="billedeContainer">
                <img src={product.image} />
              </div>
              <div className="titel">Vare: {product.title}</div>
              <div className="type">Type: {product.type}</div>
              <div className="producent">Producent: {product.producer}</div>
              <div className="unit">
                {product.unitSize} {product.unit}
              </div>
              <div className="kolli">
                Kolli mængde: {product.price * product.bulkSize}
              </div>
              <div>Antal: {product.quantity}</div>

              <div className="prisContainer">
                <div className="pris">{product.price} kr,-</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I want to make an if statement on div "type", but I can't get the syntax to work properly. I am new at react/jsx.

I want an if that says, whenever "type" is null in my array, then there shouldn't be an "type" appearing.

Comment: Looks like the simplest option for this case is an `&&` operator: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator

Answer (score 2):

Let try, when type is null, Type div will not be rendered:

```
{product.type && <div className="type">Type: {product.type}</div>}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a JSX expression to do that. If the expression evaluates to `null`, `undefined`, or `false`, nothing at all is shown where the expression appears.

You said your `product.type` may be `null`, so you can use the curiously-powerful `&&` operator:

```
{product.type && <div className="type">Type: {product.type}</div>}
```

The `{}` is the JSX expression. The `&&` operator works like this: It evaluates its left-hand operand and, if that value is *falsy*,¹ takes the value as its result, completely ignoring the right-hand operand. If the left-hand operand's value is *truthy*, the expression evaluates the right-hand operand and takes that value as its result.

So if `product.type` is `null`, `{product.type && <Stuff />}` is `{null}` and nothing gets rendered. If `product.type` isn't `null`, `{product.type && <Stuff />}` results in `{<Stuff />}`.

If you were testing something that might be `0` or some such, you wouldn't use `&&` because you'd end up with a `0` in the rendered output (since only `null`, `undefined`, and `false` are ignored). In that case you'd use a conditional expression:

```
{mightBeZero ? <Stuff /> : null}
```

---

¹ A *falsy* value is any value that's treated as `false` in a condition. The falsy values are `0`, `null`, `undefined`, `NaN`, `""`, and of course, `false`. All other values are *truthy*.

Comment: Thank you for the knowledge, I appreciate it!!

Answer (score -1):

You can use conditional statements in render.

```
item && item.type? Show type: null
```

But better is to place the code in seperate function if it is too complex.

Answer (score -1):

```
<div className="type">Type: {product.type}</div>
```

=>    `{product.type ? (<div className="type">Type: {product.type}</div>) : null }`

or

```
`{product.type && (<div className="type">Type: {product.type}</div>)}`
```